# What is the difference between Clustering management and Orchestration in docker?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I am new to docker, I can not differentiate the two concepts between Clustering and Orchestration in docker swarm. Is there any can help me to make it clear?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cluster is a group of containers or nodes. The physical state of being them together can be referred to a cluster.

Orchestration is a referred to a more intelligent activity. Orchestration requires a distributed platform, independent from infrastructure, that stays online through the entire lifetime of your application, surviving hardware failure and software updates. More [here](https://blog.docker.com/2016/06/docker-1-12-built-in-orchestration/)